# Database synchronization using JSONStore in worklight 6.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have a task to use the Synchronous adapter to create JSON storage in worklight and have automatic updation to the database when data is added to the database or vise versa.

Based on the documentation, we are calling some api at the time of the start of app to check whether the database is updated and later another api to push data. Can anyone give good documentation to do this?

Comment: @IdanAdar Please give me Step by Step procedure for JSON Sync. What is the concept of Sync Adapter

Comment: Please read the documentation provided in @cnandreu's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for JSONStore on Worklight v6.0 is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html). There's a section for working with external data [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_wl_adapter_integration.html).

Comment: @IdanAdan The above procedure gives the procedure to JSON store via push and load,I need to use sync adapter to do that.The actual scenario is that when the database is updated it should automatically update JSON Store without use of any API and similarly when the JSON Store is updated then it should be updated to the database without use of any API. The whole scenario should happen with something called as SYNC Adapter. Please Help me with it

Comment: @IdanAdar Please give me some ideas regarding my above comments.

Comment: There is no such thing as "not use any API". To invoke an adapter, you use API methods.

Comment: @IdanAdar Ok is there a way to do the JSON sync where when the database updates ,it automatically updates the JSON Store and when the JSON Store updates it automatically updates the database at the time it updates like polling in the push notification. IS there a way to do the same in adapter instead of client.The logic should be in the client not in adapter

Comment: @IdanAdar Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: @IdanAdar Ok ,but you can also tell the same in a polite way. But its alright

Comment: "Please stop mentioning my name; once is enough".

Comment: In general database know nothing about JSONStore, so for the database to push changes to JSONStore is not practical. I think you don't want the logic to be in the client, but that's by far simplest. Client simply calls a service saying "give me changes". Such a polling approach while feeling ugly has the merit of simplicity. You can optimise in the database, using triggers, to pre-prepare an answer to the question "are there any changes?".